# How to create dictionaries based on existing dictionaries in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

Well basically I have a dictionaries with UNKNOWN values `x={a, b, c, d......}` which is based on some previous inputs from the user.

Now I want to create several new dictionaries based on the values from this dictionary x, and I would like them to be in the form of `a={}, b={], c={}...`etc, the only way to get the value out of the dictionary is by calling `x[0], x[1]...`
But the thing is that I cannot call `x[0]={}, x[1]={}` and stuffs.

What should I do?

Comment: then what is the problem? go and post what you have tried.

Comment: `x.keys()` to get "unknown" keys in dictionary. but `x` can be `set()` not dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the stuff above is not really a dictionary. x is a list. To obtain the values simply search for the key.

```
>>> x = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
>>> y = ["g", "e", "r", "f"]
>>> z = {"x" : x, "y" : y}
>>> print(z["x"])
{'d', 'b', 'c', 'a'}
```

Comment: btw: `x = {"a", "b"}` is `set()` not list

Comment: `set` like `x={'a', 'b'}` has no order, you can't do `x[0] ` and `x.append()`. And `type(x)` returns `<type 'set'>`. but you can do `x|y` or `x&y` to create new `set`

Comment: now I see you changed `set` `x = {"a", "b"} ` into `list` `x = ["a", "b"]` :)

Comment: yes, it was my bad did not properly remember the difference between curly brackets and square brackets @furas